# Estimating Bayes factor in moderately high dimension (about 100)

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, importance-sampling

There is a large literature about the estimation of bayes factor using e.g. importance sampling (e.g. https://www.rocq.inria.fr/axis/COMPSTAT2010/TU-marin_paper.pdf). Most (all?) of them investigate their properties on small dimensional problems. I would like to estimate Bayes factor on a larger model (about dimension 100). Are there some methods that I can considered as doomed to fail in large dimension and are there some others that I have to try first ?

I know that the question is a quite open but I will appreciate some hints to start with.

Answer (score 1):

This paper, although focused on Genomic applications, may be of interest:

http://www.biomedcentral.com/content/pdf/1471-2105-14-85.pdf

Comment: Another method for estimating Bayes factors which is purported to be reasonable in high dimensions (though I haven't tried it) is Nested Sampling: http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.ba/1340370944, http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.0157.  The second paper exploits the power of Hamiltonian monte carlo, a particularly efficient MCMC method for high-dimensional inference.